# $n$-words from the alphabet $A=\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. How many of them have an even number of zeros and ones?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all $n$-words from the alphabet $A=\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. How many of them have an even number of zeros and ones?
I showed that the number of $n$-words from $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ with an even number of zeros is $\displaystyle X_n=\frac{4^n+2^n}{2}$ and with an odd number of zeros is $\displaystyle Y_n=\frac{4^n-2^n}{2}$. But I have not been demonstrated the number $T_n$ of $n$-words have an even number of zeros and ones. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want the number of zeros and the number of ones both to be even? Or the sum of the number of zeros and the number of ones to be even/

Comment: @Travis I want the number of  n words so that the number of zeros and the number of ones in this n-word both are even.

Comment: How did you get the expressions for $X_n, Y_n$?  Was it from a pair of coupled recurrence relations? I would define four variables $T_n, U_n, V_n, W_n$ which are the number of $n$-words with (even-even, even-odd, odd-even, odd-odd) numbers of $0$'s and $1$'s, write recurrence relations that involve them, and solve the set.  There may be a better way, but this is in my recurrence tool kit.  Clearly the asymptotic value is $4^{n-1}$, but presumably you want the other terms as well.

Answer (score 2):

For a word $w$, let $w(k)$ be the number of times that $k$ appears in $w$, and $l(w)$ the length of $w$.

Let $A_n=\{w:l(w)=n,w(0)\text{ even and }w(1)\text{ even}\}$.

Let $B_n=\{w:l(w)=n,w(0)\text{ odd and }w(1)\text{ even}\}$.

Let $C_n=\{w:l(w)=n,w(0)\text{ even and }w(1)\text{ odd}\}$.

Let $D_n=\{w:l(w)=n,w(0)\text{ odd and }w(1)\text{ odd}\}$.

Take a word $w$ of length $n$ and let's try to generate a word of length $n+1$ by appening a digit to the end.

If $w\in A_n$ then the new digit can be $2$ or $3$.

If $w\in B_n$ the new digit must be $0$.

If $w\in C_n$ the new digit must be $1$.

If $w\in D_n$ no valid word can be generated this way.

Then:

$$|A_{n+1}|=2|A_n|+|B_n|+|C_n|$$

Similarly, we get:

$$|B_{n+1}|=|A_n|+2|B_n|+|D_n|$$

$$|C_{n+1}|=|A_n|+2|C_n|+|D_n|$$

$$|D_{n+1}|=|B_n|+|C_n|+2|D_n|$$

For word of length $1$, we have: $|A_1|=2$, $|B_1|=1$, $|C_1|=1$, $|D_1|=0$.

This set of equations allows you to find recursively any $|A_n|$.

In fact, given the matrix
$$M=\left(\begin{matrix}2&1&1&0\\1&2&0&1\\1&0&2&1\\0&1&1&2\end{matrix}\right)$$
the values for $|A_n|$, etc. are given by
$$M^n\left(\begin{matrix} 2\\ 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: If anyone with math software can diagonalizate $M$ we could find a non recursive formula.