# Finding the number of $n$-words which can be formed under the given conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Consider all $n$-words from the alphabet {$0,1,2,3$}. How many of them have an even number of :-$\\$
$(a).$ zeroes $\\$
$(b). $ zeroes and ones $\\$
Source : Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel$\\$
Note : We have to answer for both parts separately. $\\$
I am stuck in this problem as to how to approach, so all I am asking from you guys is to give me any sort of approach/ strategy.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322232/n-words-from-the-alphabet-a-0-1-2-3-how-many-of-them-have-an-even-nu help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$n$-words from the alphabet $A=\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. How many of them have an even number of zeros and ones?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322232/n-words-from-the-alphabet-a-0-1-2-3-how-many-of-them-have-an-even-nu)

Comment: it answers my second part (b) but not first (a). @JitendraSingh

Comment: Can the leftmost digit be equal to $0$?